# How to implement this generic method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I got an interface just like this

```
public interface Reader<T> {
    T read(Class<T> type,InputStream in);
}
```

It's a general interface intended to read an object of type **T** from a stream. Then I know all objects I will deal are subclasses of, let's say **S**. So I create this

```
public class SReader implements Reader<S>{
    S read(Class<S> type, InputStream in){
        // do the job here
    }
}
```

But `Class<S1>` cannot assigned to `Class<S>` even though **S1** is a subclass of **S**. How do I implement this elegantly? Bounded type parameter? I am not figure that out. The only solution I have is just remove the type parameter like

```
public class SReader implements Reader{
    // the other stuff
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this interface and method? I don't understand why you would want to specify a type parameter on the Reader and at the same time pass in a Class object to the method.

Comment: There is a similar interface in one of libraries I used. It's used for de-serializing the specific class from the input stream provided.Maybe that's just a deliberate move like @Louis Wasserman said below.

Comment: well, I am thinking that, if an instance of `Reader` can only accept one particular class, so the `type` argument will always be the same, why take the Class object in the `read()` method at all? It can be passed in the constructor, or the particular subclass of `Reader` will already be specialized for this type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
public interface Reader<T> {
    T read(Class<? extends T> type,InputStream in);
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the original interface method signature. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If `Foo extends Bar`, and you want to read a `Bar` from a `Reader<Foo>`, then no; there's no way you can pass `Class<Bar>` to a `Reader<Foo>`.

Comment: If you're not allowed to change the interface, then perhaps that's a _deliberate_ move to make sure you _can't_ read subclasses.